# Why we apply [formGroup] directive to forms under square-brackets while for form-fields we apply formControlName directive without square-brackets?

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive, angular-forms

I am following an Angular 4 tutorial about reactive form. While aplying FormGroup and FormControl directives I am finding an inconsistency -

```
<form [formGroup]="formObj">
<div class="form-group">
<input formControlName="username">
```

It is applying [formGroup] directive under square-brackets while formControlName directive without square-brackets.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a directive `mydir` with the input `mydir`:

```
@Directive(...)
export class MyDir {
   @Input() mydir;
```

it can be used with or without brackets:

```
<span mydir="exp">...</span>
<span [mydir]="exp">...</span>
```

In the first case the value of the `mydir` binding will be a string `exp`:

```
export class MyDir {
   @Input() mydir;
   ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.mydir); // "exp"
```

In the second case the expression will be evaluated to whatever `exp` on the parent component contains:

```
@Component(template: `<span mydir="exp"`)
class Parent {
    exp = 'hello';

export class MyDir {
   @Input() mydir;
   ngOnInit() {
      console.log(this.mydir); // "hello"
```

Now, to your case with form directives.

The `formGroup` expects an instance of the `FormGroup` class. If you don't use `[]` the directive gets a string `formObj` instead of an object.

The `formControlName` expects a string which is the name of the control to look up in the parent form group. That is why it is used without brackets.

Comment: @JackKoppa, yours explanation is correct as well, upvoted :)

Comment: Excellent explanination @AngularInDepth.com Thank you very much

Comment: @Shadab, you're welcome :) follow [angular-in-depth publication](https://blog.angularindepth.com/) for more content like this

Comment: @MaxWizardK thanks for this explaination! Finally understood ^^ Angular syntax shortcuts are very confusing for novice

Answer (score 2):

Good question, and important to understand for Angular: directives (e.g. formGroup or formControlName) can be set to equal a string when written normally, or set equal to a value from the component TypeScript when enclosed in square brackets.

So `[formGroup]="formObj"` is setting the formGroup directive equal to the actual, dynamic object, while `formControlName="username"` is just setting equal to the string "name"